# Routes с GET-запросом в codeigniter

Tags: php, url, codeigniter

У меня возник вопрос такого рода:
Имеется url вида

http://site-name/main/sub_menu?choice=catalog&section=3,

где main это контроллер, а sub_menu - метод с параметрами.
Вопрос, как мне изменить роуты, чтобы url принял вид:

http://site-name/main/catalog/products ?

Я пробовал сделать так:
$route['catalog/products'] = 'main/sub_menu?choice=catalog&section=3';
На страницу с таким адресом выдает ошибку 404 not found.

Я понимаю, что нужно по-другому передавать в роутах параметры для гет. Но как это сделать правильно?

Comment: не совсем понятно что вы хотите. `$route['main/catalog/(:any)'] = ...;` - это?

Comment: @Manitikyl, как я понимаю, это решение подходит для пост запроса. Мне не нужно, чтобы в адресной строке вводились параметры. У меня есть статичный url catalog/products. Нужно, чтобы при его наборе в строке браузера, пхп переводил данный адрес на main/sub_menu?choice=catalog&section=3. Параметры не изменяются.

Comment: Переводил - редирект? или отоброжал но урл оставлял catalog/products

Comment: @Manitikyl, не редирект, нужно именно, чтобы при вводе catalog/products, переходил по ссылке справа от "=", но отображалось catalog/products.

Comment: Если вы хотите роутинг поменять, то нужно играть параметрами конфига enable_query_strings, controller_trigger и function_trigger. Тогда вы можете передавать get (то что после ?). https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/urls.html Но, если вы имеете ввиду, что нужно просто принять get-параметр, то в обработчике (метод/функция) анализируете (например через parse_url() ) $_GET и там уже решаете что с ним делать.

Comment: @MAX, спасибо большое, сейчас попробую первый вариант реализовать.

Comment: `не редирект` потом вы пишете `чтоб переходил`. Вы определитесь, я вроде все четко спросил. Если вы хотите чтобы по `catalog/products` показывалось то, что у вас сейчас показывается `choice=catalog&section=3` - тут. Так сделайте тогда такой роут который будет вести на тот-же контроллер, где `choice=catalog&section=3` уже дефолтные параметры.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, не решил эту проблему красиво. Я просто сделал в контроллере метод, который принимает параметры, вместо того, чтобы искать их через гет. Тогда есть два способа обратиться к нужной странице:

1. Через http://site-name/main/sub_menu?choice=catalog&section=3;

2. Через http://site-name/catalog/products, который переводит на http://site-name/catalog/3.